# Connect both way between Java Application / NodeJs / WebClient

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

I am trying to write Java application which send data to Web client (HTML/js) via NodeJs web server. Also the same java application should receive message from the web client on button click. 
Let me know how this can be done.

Any example code available on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for some example projects:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm

You can receive messages from a client with a button click, but it is only the client itself who can send the messages, so the button click should send a message to the client, asking it for a response.